# How to isolate audio signals from each other using op-amps with the same single supply?

Tags: audio, isolation, voltage-reference, single-supply-op-amp, virtual-ground

Reuploaded corrected picture, as the old one was with confusing ground connections:

[image: Reuploaded corrected picture as the old one was with confusing ground connections]

I am new here, so please be patient if I'm doing something wrong. I really need some help as I can't figure it out myself after many hours of trying and this drives me crazy.

I am working on an envelope follower/compressor (signal ducking) schematic based on quad op-amps ([TL074](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl074.pdf)). The op-amps are powered by a single 12 V supply.

The first two op-amps (IC1A/B) are getting a separate audio signal (AUDIO IN) and output it as LED light (envelope follower). The signal is mainly from a kick drum.

The third op-amp (IC1C) is used to duck the audio signal (INPUT/OUTPUT) as the LED light gets to an LDR (LED and LDR are tied together as vactrol).

The fourth op-amp (IC1D) is used as voltage follower to stabilize Vref.

The problem is that when I feed the kick drum signal into Audio IN it also appears on IC1C's output (low, but it still there).

My goal is to duck the signal without hearing the kick drum at all. I am guessing it is because of the single power supply, and the signal is getting into the other op-amp through ground. I do not have access to a rail splitter chip to try it in another way and I don't know if that would help.

Both schematics (IC1A/B and IC1C) work well if connected separately (or when one of them is disconnected from ground).

Maybe there is a way to isolate those two signals or somehow prevent the kick drum signal getting to the other opamp's output?

I tried to use to Vref as a virtual ground to ground all signals, but with no luck.

Hope that I explained everything correctly and that someone can help me solve this problem.

**UPDATE:**

Drawn new schematic. Added components as suggested (marked in yellow)

[image: Updated schematic]

Added IN and OUT capacitors and referenced Audio signals to GND, also R5 and C1 now connected to GND (before all signals were referenced to Vref).

Vref signals marked in blue for easier reading.

These changes eliminated some pops in audio signals and adding a diode in parallel with the LED stabilized IC1B output (looking at oscilloscope). The overall schematic works (a bit better than before)

But the problem still remains ...

I am hearing Kick Signal at IC1C's output, especially when no audio is fed through it.

I noticed that after these changes to the schematic the kick drum signal almost disappears when I disconnect the LDR. So I guess now the LDR's GND is the only drum signal path left.

Can this be solved somehow?

Additional noise on IC1C's output can't be seen when kick punches, but it affects the sound in a bad way:

[image: Ducked signal]

**UPDATE Nr2**

I tried other schematic updates suggested by Simon:

1. Added 100nF capacitor in parallel with C1 - that didn`t gave any changes
2. Added 100nF capacitor in parallel with ICs power supply pins - that also didn`t gave any noticeable changes (but I will leave it there now as I removed it before during tests and forgot..)
3. I am already using suggested 100nF power supply capacitor attached directly at ICs power pins (it is just not mentioned in schematic, sorry..) - so no changes here.
4. Added further low pass filter following C1 - this smoothed the wave and added some attack time. This is noticeably better and and will be considered in final design (maybe even as an adjustable setting with potentiometer).

But this did not solve problem completely.

Measuring signal at node A shows pretty smooth wave, but if measuring op-amps output to LED (added as node B in picture) signal is not so smooth.

The end of signal can be smoothed by increasing R4 resistance, but this is not the answer because the result of this is very long decay..

Also to be noticed that idle signal going in and out of IC1B is ~0,5V below Vref.
Could it be that I am hearing peaks when signal crosses Vref?
Should it be raised to Vref or even higher voltage somehow?

Made picture of all measurements:

[image: measurements at adding second filter]

Also recorded IC1Cs output with no audio fed into it. so it can be seen how Kick signal affects IC1Cs output signal:

[image: Actual problem captured]

It can be seen that adding second filter lowers peaks levels a little bit. Maybe there is a way to eliminate it completely?

**Update Nr3**

About voltage being 0.5V below Vref:
I`ve been testing other suggested combination with diode in feedback loop, to compensate voltage drop. In this combination idle voltage gets closer to Vref, but this adds instability after LED turn off and no noticeable difference in sound, so I will stay at first option I guess

Comparison of both combinations:
[image: Diodes combination comparison]

Overall schematic is working good and sound from IC1A getting to the IC1C1s output after filters is not a biggest problem anymore (now it is very low and almost couldn`t be heard)

Main problem is that glitches and peaks that I`ve mentioned in Update Nr2. appears in sound.
If decay is set low (by decreasing R5 resistance) there are peaks in sound And if I am correct they appear at the same time as LED turns on and turns off.

Could this be because of voltage difference between Idle, Vref and LED forward voltage? Maybe this could be eliminated by raising idle voltage as close as possible to the voltage where LED begins shine?

Is so - what is best way to do it?

[image: Voltage vs Audio]

Comment: _"Problem is that if I am feeding kick drum into Audio IN it also appears on IC1C's output (low, but it still there)."_ How low is low in dB?

Comment: I did not see if "decoupling" of power supply is ok ...

Comment: I don't have the right equipment to measure it because the signal is really low, but it's quite noticeable, especially when there is no signal through the third op-amp or when the signal is low-passed.

Comment: @Antonio51, I`ve tried several options. Using 0.1uF in parallel with power supply pins of IC. Any suggestions?

Comment: getting something like this working without a scope is really really hard work. It's basically working blind. You can buy an analogue scope used pretty cheap these days ... I would strongly consider it.

Comment: @danmcb, I have one really cheap digital oscilloscope but it can not detect that low signal as if I zoom in it only detects noise but not peaks that I am hearing

Comment: Is the output of IC1B supposed to be digital high or low, or is it supposed to be a slow analogue decay after the kick?

Comment: @SimonFitch output is envelope (positive wave form of kick) which controls led brightness. You can get slow decay with potentiometer R4

Comment: If you disconnect the LDR, does the kick drum audio still bleed through to IC1C output?

Comment: @SimonFitch Yes

Comment: And if you remove the LED?

Comment: @SimonFitch, it would remove some pops in audio, but kick would still be there, guess of sharing same virtual ground in all op-amps :/

Comment: @Manac probably, just ruling out other possible causes. By the way, you really need a resistor in series with that LED. It could damage the op-amp, or itself. I know you think IC1B is supposed to be analogue, but it isn't. In that configuration it's a comparator, all or nothing output. If you want LED brightness to be proportional to input potential, that isn't it.

Comment: @SimonFitch, but LED section works pretty well, i don't get what can go wrong :/ LEDs brightness looks proportional to intput signal (at least my eyes says that, don't know how to measure light signal). If i will put resistor in series with LED what will happen is that op-amp will have to raise it's output more and thats it if i am right.

Comment: @Manac I think if you are seeing the LED's brightness change smoothly, then there's oscillation at IC1B output, not smooth analogue, or even steady digital. That would suggest positive feedback due to Vref perturbation, but I still think IC1B is a comparator, and its output is digital. So even if you do fix the Vref problem, you still need to modify IC1B's configuration.

Comment: @Manac What are you using for the 12V power supply?

Comment: @SimonFitch I am using ac/dc wall adapter from old guitar fx pedal. 12V 200mA (it actually outputs 16V)

Answer (score 2):

First up, your TL074 needs split supplies - I see you are using IC1D as a voltage follower to generate an artificial "ref" at more or less mid rail "Vref". You are effectively running at +/-6V. This OK but be aware that a TL074 does not swing that close to the supply rails, there are probably better choices for running at this voltage.

IC1a is an inverting gain stage with gain of 10, this looks OK (but you might well need a small feedback cap to keep things stable).

It looks like the next stage, the pot, diode an d cap is trying to do envelope detection and use it to drive the diode. I'm not sure what use the pot is here. One problem seems to be that the circuit uses 0V as a reference when it should use the midrail Vref, if indeed you are trying to detect envelope.

Next problem is that the LED is always on. I am not sure what the - input is connected to - is that symbol (triangle on its side) 0V? If so teh LED is saturated on.

It seems to me that what you want is a more-or-less DC voltage on the cap which goes top one input of IC1B, which should be used as a comparitor. Once youi get over the threshold (which can be set by using a potential divider with a pot on the OTHER input), the LED is turned on. The output of this stage should probably connect to the LED with a series resistor (which will set LED brightness when on), the other side of the LED should go to either 0V or +12V (depending which way around you arrange things).

Another issue is that the LDR (which should be forming a resistive attenuator with R4) should be returned to Vref, not ... whatever that sideways triangle means.

(Basically you need to think of this as a split supply circuit with Vref as your real "0V" and "0V" as V-. I would suggest relabelling nodes to reflect this.)

**EDIT: OK updated circuits makes a lot more sense.** *However, what is the external ground reference? -6V or Vref? (I think it should be the -6V, you do not wanmt to expose the Vref to the external circuit.) And are there DC block caps at input and output?*

With the short attack time (set by the diode and cap), if there is any DC component to the main audio path, the kick drum is going to vary that DC level and as result you will get some audible signal. This is likely what you are hearing. You need to get rid of DC in the main audio path by using correct references and with blocking caps, and it might also help to slightly reduce attack time also with a resistor in series with diode. If you want to duck on a kick, an attack of about 10ms or so will work (experiment a bit).

Here is a suggestion of how to wire the input to reference the input to -6V, and remove DC. The 4k7 resistors are to define the DC level either side of the 10uF cap and help reduce clicks and thumps. The triangle node is your Vref. 10uF is normally charged to about 6V and right side should be positive for an electrolytic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f32k4y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Clarification and comments:**

1. you need DC block caps at input and output, even if you don't immediately hear a difference. They remove DC offsets (who knows what might be coming in at the input) which reduce headroom and can even cause other problems in bigger systems.
2. because you have a single rail system and creating an artificial mid rail "0V" (Vref) you have to be careful. The basic problem is not having a true split (i.e. dual) supply where your mid rail is a solid and reliable reference. In your circuit it is the output of a single TL074 stage which cannot sink/source much current (I'm too lazy to look it up, I think about 1mA). So this is OK for a couple of high impedance stages but any more than that (i.e. LED current) and it will move about, causing all kinds of problems. This is why you also should not connect it to the outside world. This kind of arrangement *can* work OK but it is not ideal and care is needed. Also TL074 is not a great choice for this, output driver is not that strong.
3. as noted above, avoid running the LED to your Vref. Return it to -6V (supply 0V) so it does not overload your Vref. I'm actually surprised that what you have works, I do not knop why you do not configure as a comparator with the output driving the LED via a resistor.
4. If you would make IC1c non inverting, you could simplify slightly and have higher impedance input.
5. Output resistor at 1k is too high, somethiong between 47R and 100R is normal, also you want a DC block cap here. ("Do unto others as you would have them do unto you.")

Comment: IC by itself is working good and in this application it is not needed for it so swing near supply rails. I`ve tried to use Vref as a a ground for all signals, but with no luck. Sorry for sideways triangle. it means same ground as other triangles or in this case Vref. As I said circuits are working when connected separately. Only problem is I am getting Kick sound out of IC1C`s output (I guess thru ground) and it is distorting signal which is fed thru that IC. Hope I am explaining it clear. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: I uploaded corrected version of schematic. Re-labeled nodes :)

Comment: Comment after EDIT: Thanks for your time! All grounds are connected to Vref as shown in my updated schematic. And no there are no caps at inputs and output at the moment as they didn`t gave me any changes when testing. Lets say I want ground reference to be at -6V (don`t know why) so I rewire both audio inputs via your provided circuit and add output capacitor to IC1C. In this case where other components should be grounded? R4, C1, LED and LDR? Should all stay at Vref? I need somehow to redraw this on some app as it is hard to edit paper version :)

Answer (score 2):

The way you have wired up IC1B, with the inverting input connected directly to a fixed potential, there's no negative feedback, and it won't behave linearly. It's a comparator in this configuration.

If you are seeing a smooth increase or decrease in LED brightness, it must be because there's oscillation at IC1B's output. This oscillation could well make its way to reference potential \$V_{REF}\$, and eventually to the output of IC1C.

My recommended changes are here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq4yVY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V1 represents IC1A's output. I've added R21 to throttle current from that output. Without R21, IC1A will effectively experience a short circuit to ground, via C1, every time its output peaks.

Current in LED D2 is sunk via R20, instead of directly to REF. R20 limits LED current to something reasonable for the op-amp. Since the inverting input is now no longer fixed at +6V, there is negative feedback, and the op-amp becomes a voltage follower (with offset to accommodate LED forward voltage).

I've added D3. This is to keep gain low even when IC1B output is under +6V, which keeps it's voltage gain near 1, and will help to prevent oscillation. It also serves to prevent the LED from being significantly reverse biased.

Lastly I increased C1 to 10μF, to lengthen the decay to about half a second, so that if you do build this, you will see the LED's brightness decay. Use whatever value you like for C1.

Here are plots of the potential at node A, and LED current, during and after a pulse from V1 (to emulate the kick drum signal):

[image]
[image]

---

#### Update

If after making the above changes you still have feed-through, and removing the LDR (mostly) removes feed-through, then oscillation and power supply noise has been all but eliminated, and the source of kick feed-through should be node A.

There are a couple of reasons this might occur:

- When R4 is small, the  cut-off frequency of the filter formed by C1, R21, R3 and R4 may extend well into the audio band.
- When R4 is large, the impedance of C1 at frequency becomes important. A capacitor's impedance should be zero at frequency, that's never the case in reality, and electrolytic capacitors are the worst offenders. Audio frequencies may still make it through to node A.

There are a couple of things you can do to alleviate this problem. The first is to help C1 with a smaller ceramic capacitor in parallel with it. The second is to add a further low-pass filter following C1.

The same capacitor problem can affect the 6V reference, so you should also modify that module, by adding a ceramic capacitor in parallel with C3. Naturally, IC1's supply should be bypassed with a small ceramic capacitance, as close to its power pins as possible.

Here are all those in place:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXK9B5.png)</sup>

R22 must be much greater than R21, to prevent the new filter from loading the previous one. I recommend you try each change on its own, one by one, testing in between, to help identify the worst culprits.

---

That 0.5V offset in the peak detector is due to diode D1, and is to be expected. You can eliminate it by including the diode in the feedback loop, which will compensate for the diode drop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdzUGd.png)</sup>

That's not all you can do, though. C1's charging current will be very large, tens of milliamps, potentially, all sourced by IC1A. We can offload responsibility for that current, and simultaneously reproduce the behaviour of D1 using a transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4esrb.png)</sup>

Diode D30 makes gain zero for inputs over +6V, preventing the output of IC1A from saturating against ground, and also preventing Q1's base-emitter junction from becoming excessively reverse biased.

Q1 relieves IC1A from any current sourcing duties associated with charging C1. Consequently I can reduce R3, to have the capacitor charge with much higher currents. Since IC1A output current is now a small fraction of what it was before, the IC package supplies are less liable to fluctuate.

However, this means that Q1 instead is now a cause of large, sudden supply current changes, and you should decouple its own supply (collector to bottom of C1) with a capacitance similar to C1 itself, and include a small 100nF ceramic cap in parallel with that.

Anyway, here's a plot of output \$V_A\$ as a function of an input signal of varying amplitude, centered around +6V:

[image]

As you can see, when C1 is discharging significantly fast (I set R4 to 10kΩ here), to some extent it still follows the input, and this is the cause of the kick-drum signal bleeding through to the overall output. Other than a high order low-pass filter to eliminate that, this will always be a problem. There are solutions, such as sample-hold, but their implementation will not be trivial.

If you followed A with a 20Hz low-pass 2nd or 4th order butterworth filter, then the output of that filter might look like this, where tan is 2nd order, and green is 4th order:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Updated Post, added corrected schematics and more clear description. Maybe you could take a look please?

Comment: @Manac I've updated my answer with some further changes. Can you post a trace of the non-inverting input of IC1B (my node A) during a "duck", a kick drum event? If removing the LDR removes (mostly) the problem, then oscillation and power supply noise has been all but eliminated, and the source of kick feed-through should be visible at A.

Comment: Updated my post again, tested your suggestions and added measurements with more information. Thanks for looking. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure those spiky glitches (in the grey/black plots} are due to sudden current changes, and this is why it's  ***really*** important to decouple the IC's supply with a ceramic capacitor right at the IC's supply pins. The other glitches (blue/yellow plots) are probably due to IC1B output taking time to traverse \$V_{D2}+V_{D3}\$ (a few volts) every time its input goes through zero (+6V), leading to oscillation. I'll have a think about that.

Comment: I am using 100nF ceramic capacitor connected straight to the power supply pins of IC (it is mentioned in the third point of update Nr2). I believe that those glitches in grey/black and yellow/blue plots are related to each other because are happening at the same time.

Comment: @Manac I've appended an improved peak detector, and also illustrated why the drum signal is bleeding through. I haven't solved that particular problem, yet.

Comment: Updated post. Tested other combination with diode in feedback loop, posted comparison of both combinations. I don`t want schematic to become very complicated so I will leave first option for now and maybe later will add full wave rectifier. Main problem are those peaks in audio and glitches in the output of IC1B at the end of signal (shown in Update nr2.) Also added my thoughts on voltage differences. Please take a look when you can. Thanks

Comment: @Manac You've fixed the oscillation, and I'm fairly convinced the cause of feed-through is identified, so I won't be thinking about that any more. I remind you that the TL07x has ridiculously high slew rate, and you are drawing lots of current from fast slewing outputs, so supply decoupling is not an option, nor can it be meagre. Try a 100μF electrolytic capacitor in parallel with ceramic 100nF, across the IC supplies. If you see an improvement, that's the direction to go in. If not, then new tack.

Comment: 100uF capacitor didn't help. It only adds buzz to audio. I swapped IC1A and B sections with LM358 and still not much changes. But noticed that it gets better if I swap C24 (that you provided in your update) with 1uF electrolytic (smallest i have). So I still have a room to experiment with filter section. Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: @Manac 100μF across a supply is not a lot, but it could destabilise some regulators. I would not expect 100μF across a supply to cause buzzing unless the power source can't handle that. At this point I'd want to power the circuit from a good clean source, and see what happens to those glitches. Perhaps a 9V battery (or a couple in series), or 8 AA 1.5V cells, or a 12V lead-acid battery. Anything that's not noisy or that would have a problem  with 100μF across it.

Comment: I think i got you wrong at first. I am already using 220uF across a supply (C2 in my schematics).

Answer (score 1):

You have audio ground "Vref" which is tried to be held stable by IC1D. At the same time IC1A does its best through C1 to make Vref to follow the +sign transients of the audio. The current through the led attempts  the same, it should be limited. You obviously hear that Vref is not especially stable i.e. IC1D doesn't succeed completely.

Do as said by others, have split DC supply. Or design the circuit so that the outputs of the opamps do not fight, not even through capacitors. Start by detaching C1 from Vref and connect it to the marked GND. As already said, you may also have leak through power supply or GND wires. Try to disconnect the led and C1 temporarily.

Then one idea: Kickdrum thumps may have wrong polarity. The ducking doesn't start in the beginning trail of the thump. But that obviously was not the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I do not have dual power supply and main goal is to drive circuit from simple single DC power supply. I guess circuit would run without problems connected to dual supply. Maybe I have to design circuit somehow different but I`m lost :( Detaching only C1 and connecting it to GND (-6V) would not work.

Comment: @Manac Use ordinary batteries with at least 100uF parallel capacitors to test the dual supply idea. 9V batteries for plusminus 9V voltages should work well.

Comment: guess polarity would not change much in this case. I don`t have any 9V batteries to test with. Also moving C1 from Vref to -6v help a bit, so you were right. Still testing other possible solutions that described in comments under Simon Fitch answer